How to interact with "web-app" that was fully preserved in html?
I ran into an interesting scenario. There's a website called "Online Sequencer" which basically lets you draw music notes visually, and then play them back, save and export them, change the sound using different "instrument" presets, etc.
The owners released an offline version of this website a while ago, it's a 77mb HTML file, which I am pretty sure contains more than just HTML and CSS, i think there's lots of Javascript in there, however I'm not an expert in even recognising what that looks like.
A big bulk of the html file are audio files which the program/website/app uses to generate sound. So for example "5.ogg" would be a 2 minute recording which is just every note played on a bass guitar, these are stored as text in base64 inside the HTML file, which makes the file incredibly difficult to load/parse/edit.
The beginning of the massive wall of text in the file looks like this:
</script><script>var audioData = {};audioData["0.mp3"]="data:audio/mpeg;base64,SUQzAwAAAAAAIFRY

...and trails on for literal miles. Most of the audio is ogg but I guess a few files are mp3.
My goal is just to change out one of the audio files, but normal windows notepad and notepad++ both struggle greatly and freeze up a lot, plus, it's not too easy to find where one audio file ends and the other begins, and it's just a nightmare to try and do anything through a primitive text editor.
Is there a better way to do this? Or is putting entire programs into HTML just a curse and I must struggle? I'm not a coding guy, but I may be able to build a primitive parser/reader in a language I know to find and single out each of these instances:
"audioData["11.ogg"]="data:audio/mpeg;base64" 

into seperate strings I can change out and resave, but I just want to know if there's a better way that's less work for me.
I'm assuming if I can find the ogg file I want to swap, I can encode my own ogg file (taken from the current online sequencer online version, they upgraded the quality of their samples not too long ago) into base64, and just paste mine into it's place.
Any help is appreciated, I know this is a niche question!

Hey @Gantendo, I do indeed have the "offline sequencer", but thanks for posting the links, maybe I should have done that. As you can see the oggs are easy to extract from the website. Do you recommend emeditor? If it allows loads the html without major lag and stuttering, maybe suggest it as a real answer! I will try it anyway later today, thanks for the attention. EDIT: Oh, I didn't see you extracted ALL the files from the website? This saves me some time!! There's only one file I want to change but you never know...

@Gantendo, I should think before I write... first of all thanks for the attention. My assumption was to change as little as possible, and just stick a different base64 encoded ogg into the right place. But if we could get the HTML to reference real, local files, in the same directory, we could get rid of that monster javascript array? Alternatively, is there any value in keeping the html "self contained"?
